# SQL WHERE matching any value in any column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need a table A with 4 columns for order numbers: Order1, Order2, Order3, Order4 (I know, it's horrible, but that's a given).

And I have to find the records in table B, where the match is that any value in any order column in table A could be in any order in column B:

```
A.Order1 = B.Order1 OR
A.Order1 = B.Order2 OR
A.Order1 = B.Order3 OR
A.Order1 = B.Order4 OR
A.Order2 = B.Order1 etc
```

Is there a better way to write this? 
I dread the moment they tell me they want to use 5 or 6 columns.

EDITS TO ORIGINAL QUESTION

- This is for SQL Server 2008 R2
- Table B also has 4 order columns with order numbers
- I'm looking for any order number in any order column in Table A to match any order number in any order column in Table B.
- There's no anticipated most likely finding

Comment: Can several column contain values at the same time? Or there is alway only one column filled?

Comment: No, you are stuck having multiple clauses.  That said, you could use a dynamic SQL approach to automatically generate the SQL based on the available columns.  How to go about this option would depend on what database you are using, which you have not specified (tagged).

Comment: So, `Table B` also has 4 `Order` columns?. Your `WHERE` is using every column from table A by the way

Comment: What db : MySQL, MS-SQL, Oracle, something else ?

Comment: is the idea that the 4 orders in A have to match 4 orders in B, or that at least one order in A match at least one order in B?

Comment: Are some matches more common -- there could be some optimizations if so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this with the model design you have is something (as @GordonLinoff suggested) like this:

```
where b.order1 in (a.order1, a.order2, a.order3, a.order4) or
      b.order2 in (a.order1, a.order2, a.order3, a.order4) or
      b.order3 in (a.order1, a.order2, a.order3, a.order4) or
      b.order4 in (a.order1, a.order2, a.order3, a.order4)
```

An interesting question you might have is how can I change my data model to make this work better? ... here is how:

First you have your two tables A and B.  I'm going to assume that both A and B have an unique index ID.

You can then make a support table AOrder with the following columns

```
AID 
ORDNUM
VALUE
```

If you make a similar table for BOrder then to find out if a given order is the same just join on Value and you get the AID, BID, and the two order numbers.

With this design you don't care how many order numbers there are.

You could convert your current data to this design on the fly like this and get the results you want:

```
 SELECT aord.ID as aID, bord.ID as bID, a.num as a_ordernum, b.num as b.ordernum, v 
 FROM (
   SELECT a.ID, 1 AS num, a.order1 as V FROM a
     UNION ALL
   SELECT a.ID, 2 AS num, a.order2 as V FROM a
     UNION ALL
   SELECT a.ID, 3 AS num, a.order3 as V FROM a
     UNION ALL
   SELECT a.ID, 4 AS num, a.order4 as V FROM a
 ) aord
 JOIN (
   SELECT b.ID, 1 AS num, b.order1 as V FROM b
     UNION ALL
   SELECT b.ID, 2 AS num, b.order2 as V FROM b
     UNION ALL
   SELECT b.ID, 3 AS num, b.order3 as V FROM b
     UNION ALL
   SELECT b.ID, 4 AS num, b.order4 as V FROM b
 ) bord on aord.v = bord.v
```

Answer (score 2):

You can unpivot the columns in one table using a cross apply and then check if the value from the cross apply is in any of the columns from the other table.

It does not *automatically* work if you add new columns but you will only have to add them in one or two places.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/44663/1)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
create table A
(
  Order1 int,
  Order2 int,
  Order3 int,
  Order4 int
)

create table B
(
  Order1 int,
  Order2 int,
  Order3 int,
  Order4 int
)

insert into A values
(1, 1, 40, 10),
(2, 2, 2, 20)

insert into B values
(3, 3, 3, 30),
(4, 4, 4, 40)
```

**Query 1**:

```
select *
from A
where exists (
             select *
             from B
               cross apply (values(B.Order1),(B.Order2),(B.Order3),(B.Order4)) as X(O)
             where X.O in (A.Order1, A.Order2, A.Order3, A.Order4)
             )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/44663/1/0)**:

```
| Order1 | Order2 | Order3 | Order4 |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|      1 |      1 |     40 |     10 |
```

Comment: Mikael, I don't follow... what's X(0) and X.0?

Comment: @Amarundo X is a derived table created from the values of one row of B and O is the column name for those values.

Comment: @Amarundo That is a new temporary table that is created on the fly.  Table name X column name O.  X.O references the O column in table X

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your solution is for tough guys, I believe. I chose another one because it's easier to understand for me and for future people (with my limited knowledge) looking at the code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just normalize them?  I'm assuming you have a SetID field grouping the 4(or more) orders in A and B, so you could have a table/view like:

```
    select ID, srctbl, seq, order
    from (
    select AID as ID, 'A' as srctbl, 1 as seq, order1 as order from tblA union all
    select AID, 'A' as srctbl, 2, order2 from tblA union all
    select AID, 'A' as srctbl, 3, order3 from tblA union all
    select AID, 'A' as srctbl, 4, order4 from tblA union all
    select BID, 'B' as srctbl, 1, order1 from tblB union all
    select BID, 'B' as srctbl, 2, order2 from tblB union all
    select BID, 'B' as srctbl, 3, order3 from tblB union all
    select BID, 'B' as srctbl, 4, order4 from tblB )
```

then you can say

```
select ID, srctbl, seq, order 
from (select ID, srctbl, seq, order from tbl where srctbl = 'a') ta inner join
((select ID, srctbl, seq, order from tbl where srctbl = 'b') tb on
ta.order = tb.order
```

Or, as a CTE:

```
WITH orders (ID, srctbl, SEQ, orderVal)
AS (
   SELECT ID, srctbl, SEQ, orderVal
    FROM (
    SELECT AID AS ID, 'A' AS srctbl, 1 AS SEQ, order1 AS orderVal FROM tblA UNION ALL
    SELECT AID, 'A' AS srctbl, 2, order2 FROM tblA UNION ALL
    SELECT AID, 'A' AS srctbl, 3, order3 FROM tblA UNION ALL
    SELECT AID, 'A' AS srctbl, 4, order4 FROM tblA UNION ALL
    SELECT BID, 'B' AS srctbl, 1, order1 FROM tblB UNION ALL
    SELECT BID, 'B' AS srctbl, 2, order2 FROM tblB UNION ALL
    SELECT BID, 'B' AS srctbl, 3, order3 FROM tblB UNION ALL
    SELECT BID, 'B' AS srctbl, 4, order4 FROM tblB )
)

SELECT ta.ID AS a_id, tb.ID AS b_ID, ta.SEQ AS a_seq, tb.SEQ AS b_seq, ta.orderVal 
FROM 
 (SELECT ID, SEQ, orderVal FROM orders WHERE srctbl = 'a') ta INNER JOIN
 (SELECT ID, SEQ, orderVal FROM orders WHERE srctbl = 'b') tb ON
ta.orderVal = tb.orderVal
```

Comment: I can't touch the spec of those tables.

Comment: no, you wouldn't change the schema, use the results from the select/union set in the from clause in place of 'tbl.' The answer you accepted from Hogan does the same thing.